# Meaning of parms in Sched file in linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I have been working on some performance tuning for my Java application .As a part of my analysis , i am trying to understand 2 problems

a) Meaning of 2 params under /proc/pid/sched file se.vruntime and se.sleep_start .

b) Is there any way available way for me to check what caused process context switch to happen . My process status file under /proc/pid/status shows 21 voluntary swaps . I am trying to understand what caused these swaps .

Any help or pointer might be of great help.

Thanks

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: I am sorry for posting it wrongly , I have moved the question to Unix and linux stack exchange . Will remove it from here . Thanks